# Is is necessary to normalize data before using MLPregressor?

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to use MLPregression in sklearn and I have input with different scale. I am using MLPRegressor in scikit-learn in Python.

Here is my code:

```
smlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(committee,),
                                   activation='relu',
                                   solver='adam',
                                   learning_rate='adaptive',
                                   max_iter=3000,
                                   learning_rate_init=0.01,
                                   alpha=0.01)
```

Comment: Linear models like Regressors and Kmeans do need preprocessings. Trees, on the other hand, do not.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to standardize the data in order to improve the convergence.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

Regarding the output values - You might want to standardize them too. It might help the convergence. However. it will be harder to interpret the results afterwards.

Nevertheless, if You are aiming neural networks, it might be worth looking into keras library, allowing much more up-to-date functionality, usage of GPU for training, etc.